# How to get the value of a row with Max aggregation function?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table for comments :

```
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| match_id |     timestampe      | comment  |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
|      100 | 2014-01-01 01:00:00 | Hi       |
|      200 | 2014-01-01 01:10:00 | Hi1      |
|      300 | 2014-01-01 01:20:00 | Hi2      |
|      100 | 2014-01-01 01:01:00 | Hello    |
|      100 | 2014-01-01 01:02:00 | Hello1   |
|      200 | 2014-01-01 01:11:00 | hey      |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

I want to get the following information from the table

```
SELECT match_id, max(timestampe) as maxtimestamp, count(match_id) as comments_no
FROM comments
GROUP BY match_id
order by maxtimestamp DESC
```

The previous explanation is working great but the problem is when I want to get the comment of the maxtimestamp.

How can I get the latest comment of each match (the comment of the maxtimestamp) using the most optimized query?

Comment: All you need to know is in this manual entry: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: I'd probably feel empty if a day passed without this exact question being asked. Luckily, it's never happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way.
This is pretty optimal too.

```
SELECT c.comment, m.* 
FROM 
comments c 
JOIN
(
    SELECT t.match_id, max(t.timestampe) as maxtimestamp, count(t.match_id) as comments_no
    FROM comments t
    GROUP BY t.match_id
) m on c.match_id = m.match_id and c.timestampe = m.maxtimestamp
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70efa/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about MySQL but Oracle supports window functions, so I can write something like:

```
select first_value(comment) over (order by timestamp desc)
  from comments
```

Comment: Why not look it up, so your answer could be better?  MySQL doesn't support _any_ window functions (there are a number of answers on this site detailing attempts at re-writing `ROW_NUMBER()`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy way to do it with mysql:

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT match_id, timestampe as maxtimestamp, comment
  FROM comments
  order by maxtimestamp DESC) x
GROUP BY match_id
```

This exploits the customised way mysql handles group by.

Answer (score -1):

to not use a subquery, you can use this below query

```
SELECT match_id,timestampe,comment,
       IF(@prevMatchId IS NULL OR @prevMatchId != match_id,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,
       @prevMatchId := match_id
   FROM comments
HAVING row = 1
ORDER BY match_id,timestampe DESC
```

try using `EXPLAIN` and see which queries are more optimal

here's EXPLAIN on two queries. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70efa/9/1 I am not all that familiar with EXPLAIN so maybe some experts can interpret it.

here's an EXPLAIN on two queries. if i added indexes on match_id and timestampe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30266/1/1

Comment: Well, yours will do a full table scan. It's probably the worst way to get the desired result.

Comment: (Not the downvoter, but...) - I don't know if MySQL's optimizer is smart enough, but with the right type of indices, @peter's answer could be done with index scans/probes (probably plus a row probe for the comment).  Oh, and it's parallelizeable.  Yours will require a strict sequential table scan.  And for optimization to have any real use, you need roughly real data set sizes, and indices.

Comment: I don't how to intepret the EXPLAIN from these 2 queries, one says DERIVED and PRIMARY, mine says SIMPLE I don't know the difference. but mine seems like it's doing less work in this case

Comment: A solution very similar to this will be very fast however!

Comment: @Strawberry, what do you mean? I want to see it!

Comment: I also would like to see, what Strawberry means here. But fact is, (I won't give you a guide on how to interpret explain here, though) that your query will always read the entire table. There's no filtering done at all in your query. Google the order of operations in a query. HAVING is the last thing to be done before LIMIT. The other query uses an index (fast), yours will never (very slow), cause even if an index exists, MySQL will refuse to use it, cause it has to read the data anyway. Therefore using an index would even be slower. Oh my, that's more than I initially wanted to write...

Comment: Do you think a SELECT WHERE NOT EXIST(a later record with same match Id) would be any faster. It's just that @Strawberry got me thinking what other ways there are now!

Comment: Yeah. To be honest, I'm not sure what I meant either :-) But I think I must have meant something! I'll try to have another think about it...

Comment: I tried it with HAVING timestamp = MAX(timestamp) the explain uses the index but the query doesn't work and returns zero rows it's something to do with HAVING not using the MAX(timestamp).